# Replace a word based on first n characters

Tags: vi, patterns

I have a file with data like the following:

```
ab001

ab002

ab003

ab004
```

I have to replace all words starting with 'ab' to 'ab001' i.e. after change the file should read like

```
ab001

ab001

ab001

ab001
```

I tried `%s/ab*/ab001/g` in `VI` editor, but it is not giving the expected result. I tried to Google as well but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged this with [vi](/questions/tagged/vi) and originally asked about vi, I'll explain why it didn't work in vi for you, and how to fix it. You said you originally tried:

```
%s/ab*/ab001/g
```

The way the `*` works in searches, is by matching the previous atom 0 or more times, as many as possible. From `:h /*`:

```
                            */star* */\star*
*   (use \* when 'magic' is not set)
    Matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as many as possible.
```

In this case, the previous atom is 'b', so this search will match any of these:

```
a
ab
abbb
abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

It will also match `ab001`, but it only matches the first part of it, so the match is `(ab)001`. Vi sees that you were searching for this, and replaces it with `(ab001)001`. The solution is simple. You want to match

> 'ab' followed by anything

The dot character (`.`) will match any character except for a newline. So if you search for

```
/ab.*/
```

it will match *anything* that starts with 'ab'. So you want:

```
:%s/ab.*/ab001/g
```

If this matches too much (for example, words like 'absolutely') you could simplify this to only look for digits. For example, this will match 'ab' followed by any number of digits:

```
/ab\d*/
```

and this will match 'ab' followed by exactly three digits:

```
/ab\d\{3}/
```

I would recommend bookmarking [this page](http://vimregex.com) for a quick vi-regex reference. I've found it to be extremely valuable for troubleshooting certain regexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `awk` as below:

```
cat input_file | awk '{if($1~/^ab/){print "ab001"}else{print $0}}'
```

The `awk` will search if the first field of your file start with "ab" and it will replace it by "ab001" using the `^` character, which means the `start of` the field you selected, else print the record as is.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a perl oneliner

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\bab.*?\b/ab001/g;' [file(s)]
```

The regular expression finds all elements on word boundaries that begin with 'ab' and replaces them with 'ab001'

I created this file:
ab001

```
ab002
ab003
ab004
ab005  ac001
ad0032 ab006
```

And this perl script generated this output:

```
ab001
ab001
ab001
ab001
ab001  ac001
ad0032 ab001
```

which is what I think you wanted.

The other options that I used are best explained with the Perl Documentation at the link [perlrun - how to execute the Perl interpreter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$ sed 's/ab\(.\+\)/ab001/g' -i file.txt
```

or

```
$ sed 's/\(^ab\).*/ab001/g' -i file.txt
```

A simpler and better way to do I guess,
hope that's what you' looking for.